# driver.find_elements_by_class_name returns an empty list even with sleep in Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium

Parsing for the same element using BeautifulSoup find_all(class_:"x") returns the full list, but as the elements are buttons I need to click with selenium I need them to come out as clickable elements.
The code:

```
def findPlayerInstance(self):
    sleep(5)
    player_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ElementDialogButton__StyledElementDialogButton-sc-1vrzlgb-0 dBIaHY')
    print(player_button)

def main(self):
    self.driver.get(self.URL)
    sleep(1)
    self.findPlayerInstance()
    sleep(1)
    self.driver.close()
```

The class name is correct. The driver works as it should, and another function calling driver.page_source also works, but findPlayerInstance returns an empty list.

Comment: Can you give the url to the website?

Comment: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics. I am trying to loop through the buttons with class="ElementDialogButton__StyledElementDialogButton-sc-1vrzlgb-0 dBIaHY", which are the info buttons for each player.

Comment: I "solved" it by using x-path instead. Still don't know why class_name won't work though. Now I have another problem however, neither x-path nor find_element_by_class is able to find the close button on the pop up window, and returns an error that it could not find such an element. It is given plenty of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Class names should not have space (ideally they are different classes). When you have multiple classes, replace space with `.` as shown below.

```
player_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ElementDialogButton__StyledElementDialogButton-sc-1vrzlgb-0.dBIaHY')
```